# How to hide bootstrap progress bar after it get's the maximum value 100%. Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with bootstrap progress bar. What I want is when I click the `test` button the progress bar will shown and after it get's 100% I want to hide it and when I click the test button again it will show again. How can I do this?

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1ptm607v/71/

sample code:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<progressbar value="data.progress" class="progress-striped active" animate="true" max="100"></progressbar>
<button ng-click="test()">test</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do with `ng-show` or `ng-hide` attributes.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<progressbar ng-show="data.progress < 100" value="data.progress" class="progress-striped active" animate="true" max="100"></progressbar>
<button ng-click="test()">test</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `ng-hide="data.progress==100"` to your `progressbar` tag.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eu1rdohe/)

Answer (score 1):

you can add ng-hide ng-show or **ng-if** to your tag.
like:

```html
<progressbar ng-show="data.progress < 100"></progressbar>
<progressbar ng-hide="data.progress == 100"></progressbar>
<progressbar ng-if="data.progress == 100"></progressbar>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code with jquery.

in HTML

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="" aria-valuenow="" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

in JQUERY

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.progress .progress-bar').each(function() {
            var me = $(this);
            var perc = me.attr("aria-valuemax");
            var current_perc = 0;

            var progress = setInterval(function() {
                if (current_perc>=perc) {
                    clearInterval(progress);
                } 
                else{
                    current_perc +=1;
                    me.css('width', (current_perc)+'%');
                }
                me.text((current_perc)+'%');
                if(current_perc == perc ){ // do whatever want to do after 100% complete
                    $('.progress').fadeOut('slow');
                }   
            }, 50 )
        });

    },300);
});</script>
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't noticed that these question and answer are all about on **angular js**. T answer it for **jquery**.