# How get a progress bar load body content and hide at 100%?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, load, progress-bar

i am searching a way to get a progress bar that load my body files, and be synchronize with it like when all my body has been load my progress bar is at 100% and hide... just a simple bar looking like: https://yearinmusic.spotify.com/ but i do not want to use tweenlite just for my progress bar.
Does it exist a possibility to get it only with jquery? but not the jquery ui progress bar i actually want to make my own progress bar loading less plugins as possible.

Comment: Hi, please check out [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to improve your question.

Comment: yeah its aeasy -- https://jsfiddle.net/8bxcndmk/ -- the bar is the easy thing. you need to know how to progress it in % as you downloading eg 10 files /100% = 10% at a time. if you have images in your body then you can use  http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

Comment: my images are actually in background-image in my css so for my exemple i have to load: my css + jquery + ajax.js + main.js so 25%

Comment: hmm you can load your scripts dynamically so you will need to directly have css style and JavaScript into the html page to animate the bar. as each file gets appended you can increment the bar by 25%  -- https://naveensnayak.wordpress.com/2013/06/26/dynamically-loading-css-and-js-files-using-jquery/

Comment: actually that solution will need jquery to be present. have a look on the net if you can dynamically load scripts to a page using plain Javacript. i dont think animate is available in javascript so you have to use Javascrpt  to set the width of the bar in % with some easyng transition CSS code to make the animation smooth

Comment: yes i will check it thank you ;)

Comment: ok i created a rough demo fo you. this is for loading in the files but i guess its not accurate as its simply appends file. the best way is to use images loaded and to go by that frames of reference -- https://jsfiddle.net/jw36g23j/  -im loading in jquery mobile css so the reson why is jumping a bit.

Comment: You may try this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776361/how-to-hide-bootstrap-progress-bar-after-it-gets-the-maximun-value-100-angula/40671258#40671258](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776361/how-to-hide-bootstrap-progress-bar-after-it-gets-the-maximun-value-100-angula/40671258#40671258)

Comment: You may try this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776361/how-to-hide-bootstrap-progress-bar-after-it-gets-the-maximun-value-100-angula/40671258#40671258](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776361/how-to-hide-bootstrap-progress-bar-after-it-gets-the-maximun-value-100-angula/40671258#40671258)

Answer (score 2):

**To hide an object when the side is fully loaded you can use the following jquery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function () {
    $('#yourProgressBar').fadeOut("medium");
    }, 500);
}
```

The value passed to `fadeOut()` as string or integer determines the transition duration of the fade animation.

The `setTimeout()` functions adds a nice delay effect, so that the progressbar only fades out after the specified duration (here 500ms).

To make the progressbar itself you have to either do one on your own or use one of numerous plugins. You already mentioned the jQueryUI progress bar. In my humble opinion the `bootstrap` progressbar is also quite nice. The nice thing about bootstrap and jqueryUI features is that you can choose which part of the framework/plugins you want to include, so you dont have to include the whole package.

**However if you want something ultra-light, here is an outline of how to make a progresbar yourself:**

- Create an object progressbar with a set relative or absolute width.
- Now either manipulate the background of the progressbar or add another element into your progressbar and manipulate its length.

  - How to do this? Think what about our page needs the longest time to load.
    Most probably images. You can add a class to all img-tags in our html page by the simple means of `$("img").addClass("prBar");`. Now each time one of these loads you make progress in your bar. By how much? Well the progress should be that bar's width divided by the number of elements with the class "prBar". This is calculated as follows:  `var dWidth = $('#yourProgressBar').offsetWidth / $('.prBar').length;`

Another hint: You can increment the width of your progressbar when each element is loaded by calling something like `$(".prBar").load(function(){...});`

I hope this helps you building the desired code. If you have any questions or suggestions please feel free to ask :)

Comment: so actually all my images are background-image in my css so can i use the same logic and add a class in my js and css files ?

Comment: Well yes you can use jquery to addClasses to those objects containing the backgrounds.

Comment: ok i will check it, because actually the biggest files will be (the css with the background-image, the jquery and my main.js file)

Answer (score 0):

they are some javascript frameworks that allows make web page progress bar, for me and I recommend [pace.js](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) and  [NProgress.js](http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/) because they are very simple and easy to implement

Comment: yes but it is not easy to custom your own progress bar with it