# progress bar is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

**i am trying to made progress bar but its can working plz solve it .
i am using if else for increasing the width but it's not working**

```js
var x = document.getElementById("p_bar");

for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var wid;
  wid=1;
  if(wid == 800)
    break;
  else
    wid+=8; 
  x.style.width=wid+"px";
}
  
 document.body.style.background = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);
```

```css
#cont {
    width: 800px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: cornsilk;
    position: relative;
}

#p_bar {
  width: 8px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
    <div id="p_bar"></div>
</div>
<p id="write"></p>
```

Comment: In every iteration you set wid to 1, therefore the value wid never exceeds 8.

Comment: remove this from the for loop and put it just before: `var wid; wid=1;`

Comment: The UI is never going to update in a for loop.

Comment: first you use javascript wich is async and you put a loop without any interval, then you set wid to 1 and add 8 each time, wid will never be exactly 800, it will be 801, lastly, checking for 800 and iterating 100 times are the same, you cant do both it makes no sense.

Comment: @kadath ur right my wid is in loop so evey time this make  make  change in width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote it again using functions, try this shubham:

```js
var x = document.getElementById('p_bar');
var container = document.getElementById('cont');
var write = document.getElementById('write');

var containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
var currentWidth = x.offsetWidth;

var compeleteProgress = function (step, every) {
 currentWidth = Math.min(currentWidth + step, containerWidth);
 write.innerHTML = Math.floor((currentWidth / containerWidth) * 100) + '%' // Priniting percentage
 x.style.width = currentWidth + 'px'
 if (currentWidth < containerWidth) setTimeout(function () {
  compeleteProgress(step, every)
 }, every)
}

compeleteProgress(8, 300) // When you call this function, everything starts
  
document.body.style.background = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);
```

```css
#cont{
 width: 800px;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: cornsilk;
 position: relative;
}
#p_bar{
 width: 8px;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute; 
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
 <div id="p_bar"></div>
</div>
<p id="write"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var x=document.getElementById("p_bar");
var wid = 1;

var it = setInterval(function(){

  if(wid <= 800){
      wid+=8;
      x.style.width=wid+"px";
  }else{
    clearInterval(it);
  }

}, 1000);

  
 document.body.style.background = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);
```

```css
#cont{
 width: 800px;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: cornsilk;
 position: relative;
}
#p_bar{
 width: 8px;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
 <div id="p_bar"></div></div>
 <p id="write"></p>
```

If you want to see moving progress bar, You should use `setInterval()`.

If you use just `for`, you can't see any animation.

Because, computer's calculating is so fast, so you can see only the result of `for`

Comment: the final width of the div is 801 when the container is 800, set wid to 0 and set `if(wid < 800){` to prevent that

Comment: @Neil It just sample code.. I'm so sorry. I didn't catch small mistake. But, you can change right way.

Comment: i know, that was just for OP, thats not even a big deal ;)

Comment: @neil ,young  i have one more question . i want this progress bar load in the browser when it is opening.then other contaninet of body load . what to do for this.

Comment: You can use document.onload or windows.onload to see when your page is ready and delete the progress bar, but to be able to have a bar that increments when you download a part of your page, you must use little tricks, see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559894/how-get-a-progress-bar-load-body-content-and-hide-at-100

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what behavior you really expects. The Bar size is usually changed according to any application events (in my example by timeouts). I hope this helps:

```js
 document.body.style.background = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);
 
 var setBarWidthInPercent = function(barId, value){
  var bar=document.getElementById(barId);
  bar.style.width = value+"%";
 } 
 
 setTimeout(function(){
  setBarWidthInPercent("p_bar",10)
 },500)
 
 setTimeout(function(){
  setBarWidthInPercent("p_bar",50)
 },1500)
 
 setTimeout(function(){
  setBarWidthInPercent("p_bar",100)
 },3000)
```

```css
#cont{
 width: 800px;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: cornsilk;
 position: relative;
}
#p_bar{
 width: 8px;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
 <div id="p_bar"></div></div>
 <p id="write"></p>
```